# Editing WMIC output format

Tags: batch-file

```
wmic OS get FreePhysicalMemory,TotalVisibleMemorySize /Format:Textvaluelist > Output.txt
```

Using above command in a batch, I get output as,

```
FreePhysicalMemory=1140860
TotalVisibleMemorySize=2095492
```

I want to add a single space after equal (=) sign ,sothat it may look like;

```
FreePhysicalMemory= 1140860
TotalVisibleMemorySize= 2095492
```

I am trying with below but getting error: **The syntax of the command is incorrect**

```
For /F "tokens=1 delims==" %%A in ('wmic OS get FreePhysicalMemory,TotalVisibleMemorySize /Format:Textvaluelist') do 
echo %%A %%B > Output.txt
```

or is there any other way to get the output in required format using batch ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you would consider to convert the `WMIC` output encoding from `Unicode` to `ANSI` to ommit unicode characters (like empty Echoes), a simple trick to do this is filtering the output with `FIND/FINDSTR` command(s), after applying the output filter you just need to read the output with `FOR /F` to split the string using the desired `tokens` value and `delims` delimitter.

Here is the code:

```
@Echo OFF

(For /F "Tokens=1,* Delims==" %%A in (
    'wmic OS get FreePhysicalMemory^,TotalVisibleMemorySize /Format:list ^| FINDSTR "[0-9]"'
)DO (
    Echo %%A= %%B
))>"File.txt"

Pause&Exit
```

Comment: @Elektro..its working in cmd..!!.but when i redirect output `Echo %%A= %%B > Output.txt`...Output.txt file has only `TotalVisibleMemorySize= 2095492` not the **FreePhysicalMemory** .

Comment: Of course the output contains two lines but you are attempting to redirect only one overwritting the textfile, I've edited the code to let you understand how you can redirect both lines. PS: Forgive my English speaking

Comment: @Elektro..Now Its working perfectly like you English..!! :)..Thanks..!

Comment: FWIW it still has a trailing CR on each line.

Comment: @foxidrive..Both Yours and Elektro's code are working well on my Windows 7 32 bit without giving any CR..:)

Comment: Try using this `Echo "%%A= %%B"` to check - You may find that the quotes are no longer around the string, in the output file.

Answer (score 3):

Wmic can be a weird beast.  This works here in Windows 8 32 bit.

The extra code is needed to remove the trailing Carriage Return.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
(For /F "tokens=1,* delims==" %%A in ('"wmic OS get FreePhysicalMemory,TotalVisibleMemorySize /value |find "M" "') do (
set "line=%%A= %%B"
set "line=!line:~0,-1!"
echo !line!
))>output.txt
```