# Handling of variables in for-loop of a Windows batch file

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, token

I've been investigating this a lot with threads on StackOverflow and the like, but although I feel I'm close to the solution, this problem is giving me headaches.

What I'm trying to do: When a specific external hard drive is connected (distinguished via VolumeSerialNumber over WMIC), the drive letter is found out, and mirroring is done via robocopy. The script is executed via double-click. This is what I have so far:

```
FOR /F "skip=1" %%i in ('wmic logicaldisk where VolumeSerialNumber^="XXXXXXXX" get deviceid 2^>nul') DO (
    SET y=%%i
    IF [%y%]==[] GOTO hdmissing
    SET "backuphd=%%i"
    GOTO endfor
)
:endfor

robocopy "C:\Users\Herbert\Documents" "%backuphd%\Backup\Documents" /MIR

ECHO Backup done
ECHO end

:hdmissing
ECHO Couldn't find external drive

:end
PAUSE
```

This way, the external HD is never detected (`%y%` is always an empty string). However, if I execute the script twice in the same console session, everything works as expected. But I want it to work at the first execution.

This is what I've tried so far:

- Put `SET y=dummy` at the beginning of the script. The HD is always found, triggering a backup to C: if the HD is not actually connected (apparently `SET y=%%i` doesn't alter `y`?)
- Change `%y%` to `!y!` - The HD is always found, again

Answer (score 2):

Generation 3,576 of the `delayed expansion` problem, compounded by a contaminated environment.

There's no `setlocal` apparent, so `y` remains set in the environment after the first run - hence the 'later run characteristics different from first run' phenomenon.

Within a block statement `(a parenthesised series of statements)`, the **entire** block is parsed and **then** executed. Any `%var%` within the block will be replaced by that variable's value **at the time the block is parsed** - before the block is executed - the same thing applies to a `FOR ... DO (block)`.

Hence, `IF (something) else (somethingelse)` will be executed using the values of `%variables%` at the time the `IF` is encountered.

Two common ways to overcome this are 1) to use `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` and use `!var!` in place of `%var%` to access the changed value of `var` or 2) to call a subroutine to perform further processing using the changed values.

The key in your case appears to be no `setlocal enabledelayeexpansion` and `!y!` - because `!y!` is just that - a literal string `!y!` unless `delayedexpansion` is invoked by the `setlocal` command.

(having said that,

```
IF [%%i]==[] GOTO hdmissing
```

would work just as well, as would

```
SET "y=%%i"
IF not defined y GOTO hdmissing
```

because `if [not] defined var` operates on the run-time value of `var`. `"quoting the set arguments"` ensures that any stray trailing spaces on the line are not included in the value assigned
)

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't fully aware about how the delayed expansion thing worked. If I had enough reputation, I would upvote your answer, but I solved it differently (see my detailed answer). Escaping under Delayed Expasion is a nightmare.
`IF [%%i]==[] GOTO hdmissing` doesn't work as well, because [WMIC returns a <CR> at the end](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19471675/removing-carriage-return-from-wmic-output), and this seems to be not interpreted as line break, but as own character. I figured `SET y=%%i` gets rid of <CR>.
`IF not defined y GOTO hdmissing` didn't work either on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

As Magoo already pointed out, `!y!` doesn't work, since I forgot to enable [Delayed Expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html). However, enabling it requires you to escape certain characters, which seemed quite irritating and tedious to me. It could be possible to just enclose the command in the FOR-loop with double quotes, as done in the two edits of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19471675/removing-carriage-return-from-wmic-output), but I found out after solving it differently.

What I did was moving the block

```
IF [%y%]==[] GOTO hdmissing
SET "backuphd=%%i"
```

after `:endfor`. This way, it's outside of the for loop and `%y%` gets expanded accordingly.

Mind that this solution works only because I need just one item, and because of the programming flow.

Other useful approaches might be found in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19462042/editing-wmic-output-format).

However, if you want to do the same thing: easier (though not as robust) solutions without WMIC might include

- Putting a file with a specific name on the hard drive and checking for it with [`IF EXIST`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490920.aspx) before backing up, hoping the user will not delete it, and the HD is connected to the same drive letter.
- Putting the batch script on the drive itself and work with relative path names (optional: put a shortcut on the Desktop and hope again the drive is always under the same letter)