# WMIC call in BATCH FOR command Returns unexplained Error

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, wmic

I am trying to create a Volume Shadow copy from a BATCH file but have encountered a issue I am unable to explain.

When running the below command:

```
FOR /F "tokens=3" %%A IN ('"WMIC shadowcopy call create ClientAccessible,"C:\""^| FIND /I "ShadowID"') DO SET ID=%%A
```

I receive the below error

> `Invalid format. Hint <paramlist> = <param> [, <paramlist>].`

but if I replace FIND with FINDSTR and remove the quotes from around the word I am searching for it seems to work correctly.

```
FOR /F "tokens=3" %%A IN ('"WMIC shadowcopy call create ClientAccessible,"C:\""^| FINDSTR /I ShadowID') DO SET ID=%%A
```

Can anyone explain to me why the first command will not work or what I am overlooking to make the first command work?

Yes, I know there are many other, including better, ways to achieve what I am wanting to do but for now I am just trying to better understand what I am missing here.

Thanks greatly

Comment: Do not enclose the `wmic` command line part (everything left of the pipe) in `""`, then escape the `,` like `^,`.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I was overlooking. I knew it was something simple. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems in your code:

1. You stumbled upon a strange behaviour of `FOR /F`: it does not only remove the single quotes (apostrophies, `''`) around the command to parse, it also removes enclosing quotation marks if the first and last character of the remaining string are `"` both<sup>1</sup>, so the command line that is actually tried to be executed is `WMIC shadowcopy call create ClientAccessible,"C:\""| FIND /I "ShadowID`, which is invalid of course.
2. The `WMIC` command line is enclosed in quotation marks, so even if the above issue was not there, your code would fail, because the command interpreter tries to find a command or program named `"WMIC shadowcopy call create ClientAccessible,"`, which does not exist of course.

So the corrected command line is:

```
FOR /F "tokens=3" %%A IN ('WMIC shadowcopy call create ClientAccessible^,"C:\" ^| FIND /I "ShadowID"') DO SET "ID=%%A"
```

Note that you need to escape the `,` herein (similar to the pipe).

<sub>1)  You can affirm that by trying the command line `FOR /F "tokens=3" %%A IN ('"WMIC" shadowcopy call create ClientAccessible^,"C:\" ^| FIND /I "ShadowID"') DO SET "ID=%%A"`, which fails, and `FOR /F "tokens=3" %%A IN ('^""WMIC" shadowcopy call create ClientAccessible^,"C:\" ^| FIND /I "ShadowID"^"') DO SET "ID=%%A"`, which works because there are additional `""` put around (they are escaped like `^"` so that the command line does not need to be altered in terms of escaping; you could also state the `"` literally, but then you needed to unescape the `,` and the `|`).</sub>

---

In addition, I recommend to nest another `FOR /F` loop inside yours, because `WMIC` returns Unicode text, which could leave artefacts (orphaned carriage-return characters) when being parsed by `FOR /F` (as it expects ANSI text); an additional parsing phase eliminates such noise:

```
FOR /F "tokens=3" %%A IN ('WMIC shadowcopy call create ClientAccessible^,"C:\" ^| FIND /I "ShadowID"') DO FOR /F "delims=" %%B in ("%%A") DO SET "ID=%%B"
```

This method is credited to [dbenham](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1012053/dbenham) -- see his answer to [Why is the FOR /f loop in this batch script evaluating a blank line?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14658784) and also his external article [WMIC and FOR /F : A fix for the trailing <CR> problem](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4266).

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the output of the WMCI command is in unicode. See this post [Editing WMIC output format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19462042/editing-wmic-output-format)

Comment: This is not true, because the OP does not even come to that point due to the problems I pointed out in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37158106); as soon as the syntax issues are resolved, the Unicode conversion issue you mention needs to be taken into account...